# Language Translation for picklist values in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, translation, customlabel, selectoption

There are 2 picklist fields in my VF page. I successfully translated the whole VF page using custom labels (into Spanish), but the picklist values are not translated.  How to translate them?

Here's the VF code of the picklist fields.

```
<div class="form-label left "><apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.T97}" /></div>
<div class="form-field">    
    <apex:inputField id="Program_Duration" value="{!app.Program_Duration__c}" required="true"/>
</div>

<div class="form-label left "><apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.T95}" /></div>                                
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!app.Program_Opinion__c}" id="start-opinion" required="TRUE">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1 Week" itemLabel="1 Week"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2 Weeks" itemLabel="2 Weeks"/>                                            
    </apex:selectRadio>                                                                       
</div>
```

I dont want to use {!label.1Week} and {!label.2Weeks} in the 'itemLabel' for for the Program_opinion__c picklist field (2nd picklist) as there are more than 30 weeks.  I don't want to create so many custom labels.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: You have to. The labels are there for it. In my org for example we have over 2000 labels in a big project. Or translate your picklist values in translation workbench and use `inputField` or `outputField` on the visualforce page.

Comment: @mast0r that's worthy of an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use labels or [translation workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=adding_and_editing_translated_languages.htm&language=en_US).

There are some options to display translated picklists on the visualforce.

1. A salesforce standard way to is to use `apex:inputField` tag with assigned sobject field of type picklist. In this case a picklist will be generated automatically with respect to the current user language. All you need to do is translate each picklist value with translation workbench 
    [image]
2. The second option is to create a picklist on the visualforce page with `apex:selectList` tag and use labels for each `apex:selectOption` entry (like in your example). That's not bad at all to use labels, even if you need to create a tons of it. It is absolute ok to have several hundreds or even thousands of label, depends on the project size.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So, for the first picklist values, I can use the Translation workbench --> Translate option to translate because Im using <apex:inputField> anyways, so I dont need to change the code for this.  And for the 2nd picklist as you said I will create custom labels for each picklist value.  Let me know if Im wrong.  thanks much

Comment: @BruceLee You are right :)

Comment: I have a problem with this. I created labels and used them in itemLabel for picklist label. itemLabel="{!$Label.T001}".  It is translated good. But the value stored is NOT translated after save. 

Also this rendered condition is not working. 
rendered="{!app.Health_Indicated__c == '{!$Labe.T001}' }"

Comment: I created a new detailed question for this.  Pleas help. This is the link. Thanks 

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48218/rendered-not-working-translated-picklist-value